# Is Map attribute in DefaultLinkGenerator link() method thread safe?

Tags: grails

We built an Grails (2.3.7) application where we are overriding the link(Map attr, String encoding = 'UTF-8') in DefaultLinkGenerator class. The reason we are doing this is to have the same URL throughout our application as it was business requirement from the customer. Basically in the overriding link() method, we are modifying the Map with new request parameters.

Now in Production we are seeing the following exception which occurs sporadically and we haven't been able to reproduce it locally.

```
2014-09-29 01:04:06,257 StackTrace ERROR Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlCreatorCache$ReverseMappingKey.<init>(UrlCreatorCache.java:196)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlCreatorCache.createKey(UrlCreatorCache.java:62)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder.getReverseMappingNoDefault(DefaultUrlMappingsHolder.java:265)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder.getReverseMappingNoDefault(DefaultUrlMappingsHolder.java:257)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.DefaultLinkGenerator.link(DefaultLinkGenerator.groovy:213)
at gov.texas.multitenant.core.mapping.MultitenantLinkGenerator.super$2$link(MultitenantLinkGenerator.groovy)
```

The code in 'UrlCreatorCache$ReverseMappingKey' that throws the above ArrayIndexOutOfException can happen only when Map attribute (params) gets mutated during the loop. The excerpt of that code is below.

```
paramKeys = new String[params.size()];
paramValues = new String[params.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry entry : params.entrySet()) {
    **paramKeys[i] = String.valueOf(entry.getKey());** //throws exception here
    String value = null;
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof CharSequence) {
        value = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
    }
    ...
    paramValues[i] = value;
    i++;
}
```

Now my question is, does this Map attribute THREAD SAFE? Can it get mutated between threads since we are modifying it?

Any feedback will be great appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't know inside that method - anything implementing the `Map` interface is allowable. But that's not important - you're causing the problem (by being one of two concurrent editors of an apparently non-threadsafe instance) and can easily fix it.

Instead of modifying the map, create a new one (any `Map` implementation will do since only your code and the code in that method can access it) and modify that, and pass that in for link generation. Then throw it away and use the real map for further calculations. Something like

```
def attrs = ... // the 'real' map
def copy = [:] + attrs
copy.foo = 42
copy.bar = 'a very high one indeed'

String link = linkGenerator.link(copy)
// 
...

def foo = attrs.foo // not available, set in copy, but no longer using that
...
```

Comment: Burt, thanks much for the suggestions. We are thinking something similar of what you suggested. One thing to point though, currently after the modifying the map, we are passing it to 'super.link(modifiedMap)' class. Do you think creating a new Map and passing it along would/could fix the problem?

Comment: Without looking closer it's hard to know, but my guess is that there are no other concurrent updates, so modifying a copy lets you use merged data without trigger the error, and all other calls would use the original map

Comment: Thanks Burt again. We are going to try to replicate the issue locally again and then modify the code (creating new map) and see if that fixes the issue. Will let you know.